# Locally hosted website with IIS cannot be read on browser ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: iis, dns

I would like to access my locally hosted website using a domain name as the URL address, however, I have encountered a strange problem. When typing the domain name and executing the page request, Chrome returns the error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and shows a page which states (screenshot below is in Norwegian) "This page is not working. publicproductionoverview.local did not send any data".

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvtqg.png)

I have tried watching several YouTube tutorials, searched a lot on the internet (including stack overflow) and tried different configurations. As of now the following screenshots describes my configuration.

[Avaliable DNS servers from my computer (first one is the locally hosted DNS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkjyI.png)

[Forward lookup zone in DNS manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/954Iy.png)

[Reverse lookup zone in DNS manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POnrj.png)

[DNS information in DNS manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTAhT.png)

[Bindings of my site in IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI5Qm.png)

To show that both the web server and DNS server is running, the following screenshot is the result of the ping to the website using its domain name.

[Ping result (working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQndu.png)

Finally, my question is:
How can I resolve the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error?

I am using Windows Server 2019, IIS 10 and DNS Manager (installed Server Manager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have narrowed the issue down to a restriction set on the network at my workplace. What worked for me (at least now in the development phase) was to write the domain names in the hosts file, located in System32 -> drivers -> etc, without point (.) notation in the domain name. For instance, publicproductionoverview worked, but not publicproductionoverview.local.

This question is therefore too narrow or specific for making a general answer. However, I recommend that the question should not be deleted, as it may serve as a "point in the right direction" for others who has similar problems on their local or wide network.